# MySQL - mysqldump --routines to only export 1 stored procedure (by name) and not every routine

Tags: mysql

So we have a lot of routines that come out from exporting. We often need to get these out in CLI, make changes, and bring them back in. Yes, some of these are managed by different folks and a better change control is required, but for now this is the situation.

If I do:

```
mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db
```

then great, I have 200 functions. I need to go through a file to find just the one or set I want.

Is there anyway to mysqldump routines that I want like there is for tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your exact question: no.

But this will probably give you what you want.

Take a look at `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` and `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-procedure.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-function.html

Those commands allow you to dump the code for one routine at a time.

Answer (score 15):

Another way to go about this would be the following. Do note, however, that you have to have root privileges in the target database in order to import rows into mysql.proc:

```
mysqldump --compact --no-create-info --where="db='yourdatabasename' AND type='PROCEDURE' AND name IN ('yoursp1', 'yoursp2')" --databases mysql --tables proc
```

Comment: To restore the script created by this dump, you'll need to qualify the 'proc' table reference to mysql.proc manually. 
However in general, I find the output of this method much more flexible than the traditional mysqldump --routines method. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need root. Just add the credentials of an mysql user with -u and -p. Like this: mysqldump -udbadmin -pPASSWORD --compact --no-create-info --where="db='database' AND type='PROCEDURE' AND name IN ('procedure_name')" --databases mysql --tables proc

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to dump a single function or procedure using the command that Ike Walker mentioned, but the `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` and `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION` commands don't allow to select only a few columns from the output.

Here is a example of a Windows batch command line to dump a single procedure, using the system table `mysql.proc`:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=myconfig.cnf --skip-column-names --raw --batch mydatabase -e "SELECT CONCAT('DELIMITER $$\nCREATE PROCEDURE `', specific_name, '`(', param_list, ') AS \n', body_utf8, ' $$\nDELIMITER ;\n') AS `stmt` FROM `mysql`.`proc` WHERE `db` = 'mydatabase' AND specific_name = 'myprocedure';" 1> myprocedure.sql
```

This will redirect the output of mysql into the file **myprocedure.sql**.

The `--batch` option tells the mysql client to remove the table borders from the output.
The `--skip-column-names` option removes the column headers from the output.
The `--raw` option tells MySQL to not escape special characters on the output, keeping new lines as is instead of replacing them with `\n`.

And if you want to dump ALL the procedures in different files, this example in batch should work:

**dump-procedures.bat**

```
@echo off

REM set the target database
set database=mydatabase

REM set the connection configuration file
set auth=--defaults-extra-file=myconfig.cnf

REM set the routine type you want to dump
set routine_type=PROCEDURE

set list_file=%routine_type%S.csv

if "%routine_type%"=="PROCEDURE" (
set ending=AS 
)
if "%routine_type%"=="FUNCTION" (
set ending=RETURNS ', `returns`, '
)

echo Dumping %routine_type% list to %list_file%
mysql %auth% --skip-column-names --raw %database% -e "SELECT routine_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND ROUTINE_TYPE = '%routine_type%';" 1> %list_file%

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%list_file%) do (
    echo Dumping %routine_type% %%a
    mysql %auth% --skip-column-names --raw --batch %database% -e "SELECT CONCAT('DELIMITER $$\nCREATE PROCEDURE `', specific_name, '`(', param_list, ') %ending% \n', body_utf8, ' $$\nDELIMITER ;\n') AS `stmt` FROM `mysql`.`proc` WHERE `db` = '%database%' AND specific_name = '%%a';" 1> %%a.sql
)
```

It works in 2 steps, where it first dumps the list of all procedures into the file **procedures.csv**, and then iterates in each line and uses the names of the procedures to dump each procedure in a different file.

In this example, I am also using the option **--defaults-extra-file**, where some configuration parameters are set in a different file, and allows to invoke the command without needing to type the password each time or writing the password inside the batch itself. I created a file with this content

**myconfig.cnf**

```
[client]
host=localhost
port=3306

user=myusername
password=mypassword
```

This solution also works with function, defining the routine_type variable to:

```
set routine_type=FUNCTION
```

Comment: where define this variable %header%

Comment: @Bill.Zhuang thanks for the observation. That variable was from an old version where I defined the column name in other part of the script.

I tested this new solution only replacing the database name and the defaults file, and it works.

Comment: For some reason, this loses all output escaping within strings in the stored procedure body.

Answer (score 2):

I have written the solution within bash.

For one procedure

```
mysql -NB -u root my_database -e 'show create procedure `myProcedure`' |\
xargs -n 1 -d '\t' echo |\
egrep '^CREATE' |\
xargs --null echo -e >
```

For all procedures

```
mysql -NB -u root -e 'SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = "my_database" AND ROUTINE_TYPE = "PROCEDURE"' |\
xargs -n 1 -I {} mysql -NB -u root my_database -e 'show create procedure `{}`' |\
xargs -n 1 -d '\t' echo |\
egrep '^CREATE' |\
xargs --null echo -e
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

This (in my opinion) is the easiest and fastest way to export just the creation code for one single procedure

```
mysql -hHOST -uUSER -pPASSWORD -B -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE DATABASE.PROCEDURE;'
```

If you want to replace \n with a real newline, just use sed

```
mysql -hHOST -uUSER -pPASSWORD -B -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE DATABASE.PROCEDURE;' | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

Answer (score -1):

This is trick,

1. create DATABASE to local.
2. dump your DATABASE include your STORE PROCEDURE to local.
   or
   just use mysql*yog and copy database, check STORE PROCEDURE (example: 1 store procedure) to local server.
3. dump your DATABASE local . yeah, you have 1 store procedure in your dump. remember use --routine if u want sp/events only.

trick is fun, isn't lazy, just tricked.