# How to write stored procedures to separate files with mysqldump?

Tags: stored-procedures, scripting, mysql

The mysqldump option `--tab=path` writes the creation script of each table in a separate file. But I can't find the stored procedures, except in the screen dump.

I need to have the stored procedures also in separate files.

The current solution I am working on is to split the screen dump programatically. Is there a easier way?

The code I am using so far is:

```
#save all routines to a single file
mysqldump -p$PASSWORD --routines --skip-dump-date --no-create-info --no-data --skip-opt $DATABASE > $BACKUP_PATH/$DATABASE.sql
#save each table to its file
mysqldump -p$PASSWORD --tab=$BACKUP_PATH --skip-dump-date --no-data --skip-opt $DATABASE
```

Even if I add `--routines` to the second command, they will not get their own files.

Comment: what is your complete mysqldump command?  Did you remember `--routines`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysqldump` command does not support dumping stored procedures into individual files.

But, it is possible to do it using the `mysql` command.

```
mysql --skip-column-names --raw mydatabase -e "SELECT CONCAT('CREATE PROCEDURE `', specific_name, '`(', param_list, ') AS ') AS `stmt`, body_utf8 FROM `mysql`.`proc` WHERE `db` = 'mydatabase' AND specific_name = 'myprocedure';" 1> myprocedure.sql
```

For a more complete example, using Windows Batch, look into my answer on another question. 
[MySQL - mysqldump --routines to only export 1 stored procedure (by name) and not every routine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518459/mysql-mysqldump-routines-to-only-export-1-stored-procedure-by-name-and-not/25629708#25629708)

Answer (score 4):

I created a script to output to a separate file.

https://gist.github.com/temmings/c6599ff6a04738185596

example: `mysqldump ${DATABASE} --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --compact | ./seperate.pl`

File is output to the directory(out/).

`$ tree
.
└── out
    ├── FUNCTION.EXAMPLE_FUNCTION.sql
    └── PROCEDURE.EXAMPLE_PROCEDURE.sql`

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is: it is not possible without post-processing

Answer (score -1):

This writes table definitions (not SPs) fwiw:

```
mysqldump -u<username> -p<password> -T<destination-directory> --lock-tables=0 <database>
```

One snag I ran into was, make sure you put enough permissions on . I just did chmod 777 on it.

A note on this--MySQL will write out the table structures in .sql files, and the data in .txt files. I wish it would just do it normal, thanks.

Comment: What does this do? I can't test it on Windows because I get this error: `mysqldump: Got error: 1: "Can't create/write to file 'C:\test\attributes.txt' (Errcode: 13)" when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'`, but if it *really* does what the OP is asking, then I will load up a Nix.