# Mysqldump specific stored procedures/functions but not others

Tags: mysql

I know that mysqldump does not include stored procedures/functions by default and that you have to use the -routines to include them. I am also aware that to dump just the functions and stored procedures you would use the following.

```
mysqldump --skip-triggers --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt your_db_name > your_output_file.sql
```

The issue I have is how dump specific stored procedures/functions and not all of them?

So this is what I have tried **--ignore-table=your_db_name.FUNCTION1** and even **your_db_name FUNCTION1** to output just that function. None of these have worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518459/mysql-mysqldump-routines-to-only-export-1-stored-procedure-by-name-and-not

Comment: Thanks sorry did not see this.