# Take dump of specific store procedure mysql

Tags: mysql

```
I need to take backup of few store procedure 'proc1 proc2 proc3 proc5 ' using
MYSQLDUMP command.

MYSQLDUMP -u root -p --routines 'proc1 proc2 proc3 proc5 mydb >mydump.sql
It is not working.
```

Show create is for one procedure, If I have multiple then how to take through
   MYSQLDUMP.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.codensys.com/backup-your-stored-procedures-in-mysql) and [this](http://www.ducea.com/2007/07/25/dumping-mysql-stored-procedures-functions-and-triggers/). See if it helps...

Comment: This may help too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7080270/